# Inverse image of a compact set is compact

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, $X$ compact, $f : X \to Y$ continuous. Then the preimage of each compact subset of $Y$ is compact.

With the stipulation that $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, this is a theorem in Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis*. The proof uses sequential compactness. Is this theorem true in general (*i.e.* can it be proved with covering compactness alone)?

Comment: Are your spaces Hausdorff?

Comment: It holds if $Y$ is Hausdorff. If it isn't, generally not.

Comment: Maybe. Does it matter? It's not a homework assignment or anything, some friends and I were just wondering.

Comment: Oh okay, can you post a counterexample?

Comment: @BrianBi If $Y$ is Hausdorff, a compact subset is closed, so the inverse image is closed in $X$, hence compact. If $Y$ is indiscrete…

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The claim is true if $Y$ is Hausdorff: if $C\subseteq Y$ is compact, then it is closed; therefore $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X,$ hence compact.

For a counterexample, take $Y=X$ with the indiscrete topology and $f$ the identity map. Then every subset of $Y$ is compact, which can be easily arranged for $X$ not to.

Answer (score 12):

A map $f:X\to Y$ is called *proper* if the preimage of every compact subset is compact. It is called *closed* if the image of every closed subset is closed.

If $X$ is a compact space and $Y$ is a Hausdorff space, then every continuous $f:X\to Y$ is closed and proper.

Here are some examples where $f$ is not proper:

- With $X$ compact: Let $X=[0,1]$ and $f=\text{Id}:(X,\tau)\to(X,\sigma)$ where $\tau$ is the Euclidean topology and $\sigma$ is the cofinite topology.
- With $Y$ Hausdorff: Let $f:\Bbb R\to\{*\}$ be the constant map.

Comment: Interesting! But I think the "proper map" terminology isn't very good. If we view sets as carrying the discrete metric, then a map between sets is proper iff every fiber is finite. I just don't think the word "proper" really fits in this case...

Answer (score 11):

This is not true in general.

Let $X=Y=[0,1]$. Take $X$ with the usual topology. For $Y$, take the topology
$$\tau=\left\{\varnothing,Y,(1/2,1]\right\}.$$
Then $id:x\in X\mapsto x\in Y$ is continuous, but $(1/2,1]=id^{-1}(1/2,1]$ is not compact, although $(1/2,1]$ is compact in $Y$.

On the other hand, if $Y$ is Hausdorff, then every compact of $Y$ is closed, so the inverse image of compact sets is closed, hence compact.

Comment: Why is $\left (\frac{1}{2}, 1\right ]$ compact in $Y$ but not in $X$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Use the definition of compactness to see $(1/2,1]$ is compact in \(Y\). Non-compactness in $X$ follows from Heine-Borel (check any real analysis/elementary topology textbook).

Comment: Ok!! Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:**  This answer is intended to compliment the above, and thought it is not fully generally, but is has often been helpful in my experience...

If $Y$ is $\mathbb{R}$ then its sufficient for $f$ to be [coercive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function).  When $X$ is a topological vector space, the coercivity condition reduces to the requirement that
$$
\lim_{\|x\|\to \infty} f(x)=\infty,
$$
which is typically easy to check.