# Question about Proof of 3.15 in Rudin's Functional Analysis

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-verification

In Rudin's Functional Analysis, the following claim is made (Banach-Alaoglu theorem):

> If $X$ is a TVS and $V$ is a nbhd of $0_X$, then $$ K_V \equiv \{ \Lambda\in X^\ast | |\Lambda(x)|\leq1\forall x\in V \} $$  is weak-* compact.

Rudin gives some long-winded proof, but I was able to come up with the following proof, which I wonder about the validity of. Thus I would be very glad if anyone could tell me where it's false.

For each $x\in X$, define $f_x:X^\ast\to\mathbb{F}$ by $f_x(\Lambda):=\Lambda(x)$. Then by the definition of the weak-* topology on $X^\ast$, all of these maps are continuous.

Next, for each $x\in X$, define $K_V(x) := \{ \Lambda\in X^\ast | |\Lambda(x)|\leq1 \}$.

Then $K_V = \bigcap_{x\in V} K_V(x)$, and $K_V(x)=f_x^{-1}(\bar{B_1(0_\mathbb{F})})$, where $\bar{B_1(0_\mathbb{F})}$ is the closed unit ball around $0_\mathbb{F}$. Thus we find that $$ K = \bigcap_{x\in V} f_x^{-1}(\bar{B_1(0_\mathbb{F})}) $$

But as $\bar{B_1(0_\mathbb{F})}$ is compact in $\mathbb{F}$, $\mathbb{F}$ is Hausdorff, and $f_x$ is continuous, we find that $f_x^{-1}(\bar{B_1(0_\mathbb{F})})$ is compact in $X^\ast$, and also, by continuity, closed. So $K$ is a closed subset (being an intersection of closed subsets) of a compact set (any of the $f_x^{-1}(\bar{B_1(0_\mathbb{F})})$) and is hence also compact.

Comment: Why  is the preimage in the third-to-last line compact?

Comment: The pre-image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676802/inverse-image-of-a-compact-set-is-compact

Comment: If the domain is compact...

Comment: You're welcome. Idk how much you're liking Rudin, but I've been loving Zimmer's short book "essential results of FA" FWIW. For instance his proof of Banach Alaoglu is super short, but it might just be a terse rendering of the same argument Rudin gives.